# Javascript Drag and Drop function order

Tags: javascript

```js
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var ziel = document.getElementsByClassName('ziel');
var dragItem = null;

for (var i of li) {
  i.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
  i.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
}

function dragStart() {
  dragItem = this;
  setTimeout(() => (this.style.display = 'none'), 0);
}

function dragEnd() {
  setTimeout(() => (this.style.display = 'block'), 0);
  dragItem = null;
}

for (j of ziel) {
  j.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
  j.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
  j.addEventListener('drop', Drop);
}

function Drop() {
  this.append(dragItem);
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragEnter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mk33y/pen/NWvZomQ)

I have the problem, every time I take a list item and drop it in the same `<ul>` it gets thrown to the bottom of the list every time. I want it to stay in the same place if I let it go in the same `<ul>` but if I drop it in another `<ul>` it should be listed at the bottom of course. Does anyone have any idea how I do this?

Comment: Hi @Franziska , it would help someone who try to solve your question, if you provide your entire code. You could reproduce your code Codepen or any other similar service.

Comment: Thanks, i've added codepen in the main question.

Comment: `this.append(dragItem);` will always append the `dragItem` at the bottom, check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append .